# Using cURL twice on same page, first to authorize then to get data

Tags: php, php-curl

I have the following code for a cURL request to authenticate as a first step:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.example.com/v1/api2/login?grant_type=client_id",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: Basic abcdefhjijkjljpeqrperpqweprwqprqrp",
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
   echo $response;
}
$response = json_decode($response);
```

This code works fine and returns the Bearer token object.

UPDATE: Here is the response from the first cURL request:

```
{"access_token":"afasfadsfaewrererearaere34343434-34-3403-403-403-3-3434343434343","type":"Bearer"}
```

Now, after getting the Bearer token I'd like to make a GET request using the same API, and here is where I have problems:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://api.example.com/v1/api2/event/adfafsafsfafsffs",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: Bearer " . $response['access_token'],
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

This code times out when I try to run it.

Here is the documentation for formatting the request:

```
curl -X GET \
  http://api.example.com/v1/api2/event/adfafsafsfafsffs \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer bzJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9'
```

How can I format the second cURL request so that it works with the instructions above and I can make a GET request after authenticating?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you please verify that `$response` from the first request is indeed an array? Finally, please confirm for us what the generated output of `"Authorization: Bearer " . $response['access_token']` is.

Comment: when I try to echo $response['access_token'] I get the "illegal string offset" error and same thing when I try to print_r($response['access_token']); But also if I just copy and paste the access token in manually to the second cURL request it gives me a timeout

Comment: @waterloomatt I added the response output in my OP

Comment: @waterloomatt, I was able to extract the access token out by adding json_decode($response) first... however I'm still getting the timeout response on the second cURL request

Comment: If the connection is timing out, it sounds like a server-side problem. Contact the API maintainer for support.

Comment: Can you point us to the documentation for the API provider or is it private?

Comment: yea its private unfortunately :( otherwise I'd be happy to

Comment: Are you able to make a successful API request at all to this endpoint (possibly without using CURL)? Can you confirm that it is working?